# InputStream does not work if used multiple times

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I'm having some problems with an InputStream. I'm writing a little Android application and part of it has to fetch HTML code from a website. Generally, it works fine, but sometimes (usually the second time it's called, but it may also take a few tries to reproduce this) it will just skip the InputStream (I noticed this since it takes a few seconds while debugging, but every time it fails it will just immediately skip to the next line). Any ideas what could be causing this and how to fix it?

```
    private class fetchdata extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            public Activity activity;      
            public fetchdata(Activity a)
            {
                activity = a;
            }  
            protected Void doInBackground(Void...voids)
            {
                String[] page = new String[16384]; //Number is just for testing, don't worry
                try {
                                page = executeHttpGet();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                page[0] = "Error";
                        }
                displayFetchedData(page);
                return null;
            }
    public String[] executeHttpGet() throws Exception {
         URL u;
        InputStream is = null;
        DataInputStream dis = null;
        String s;
        int i = 0;
        int hostselection;
        boolean skip;
        String[] page = new String[16384];
        String[] serverurls = new String[2];
        addSecurityException();
        SharedPreferences dataprefs = getSharedPreferences("serverdata", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);        
        hostselection = dataprefs.getInt("selectedhost", 0);
        SharedPreferences preferences;
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
        serverurls[0] = preferences.getString("server01", "");
        serverurls[1] = preferences.getString("server02", "");
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
         skip = false;
         if (j == 0)
         {
                         if (hostselection == 0 || hostselection == 1)
                             {
                                 Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator(activity, false));
                             }
                         else
                         {
                                 skip = true;
                         }
         }
         if (j == 1)
         {
                         if (hostselection == 0 || hostselection == 2)
                             {
                                 Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator(activity, true));
                             }
                         else
                         {
                                 skip = true;
                         }
         }
         if (skip == false)
         {
                         try {
                            u = new URL(serverurls[j]);
                            is = u.openStream();        //LINE IN QUESTION
                            dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
                            while ((s = dis.readLine()) != null)
                            {
                                if (s.length() > 18)
                                {
                                        page[i] = s;
                                        i++;
                                }
                            }
                         }
                         catch (IOException ioe)
                         {
                                 ioe.printStackTrace();
                         }
                         is.close();
                      }
        }
        return page;
   }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unrelated, but you aren't closing the DataInputStream.

Tell us more about the skipping.  Is an exception raised? Is it possible that when you are running it outside of debug mode it is somehow referencing stale class files?  The only thing I can imagine is that somehow your debug and normal classes are somehow different.

Comment: I thought the DataInputStream automatically closes when the InputStream is being closed. There is no exception raised. It will simply not read the page (thus the array "page" is empty). When debugging, the code line for line, openStream() will take a few seconds. However, sometimes it immediately continues, which is why I called it "skipping". The result is the same as when I don't debug, which is why I think that the behavior is the same as well.

Comment: When it skips, is any content read or is no content read?
I'm not sure DataInputStream will automatically close.  InputStream will have no reference to it, so to me it seems unlikely.  InputStream should automatically close if DataInputStream is closed, since DataInputStream wraps the InputStream.

Comment: I just added a line which closes the DataInputStream, however, the problem still persists. No content is read when that error occurs, which will leave the array "page" empty (null).

Comment: It could be that there is in fact no data to read.  Check the available() field on the input stream and see whether any data is available to read.  Perhaps the connection is failing?

Comment: This is probably it... It might just be a problem with the emulator, I'll have to create a failsafe for faulty connections, anyway. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `BufferedInputStream` out of the input stream you get, then Call [`mark()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#mark%28int%29) method with the input stream length as parameter. Call `reset()` when you need to reuse the stream next time.

Comment: Hey, thanks for you answer, but I don't want to reuse the stream, I'd like it to reload completely (in case the page has been updated, or will it reload the page if I do what you suggest?).

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question. Why not open a new stream everytime?